# How to create a custom legend with ggplot2 and ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having issues creating a custom legend when using function [ggarrange](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggarrange.html) with ggplot2 plots.

The current plot I am making is the one on the left hand side, but I want the legend to look like the one on the right hand side:

[image: plots]

In other words, I have a set list of colours with custom text, and I want them all to be included in the legend, regardless of the colours used in the plot.

The colours I want for the legend are stored in object chart:

```
chart <- structure(list(plotvals = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1), Colour = c( 
"#000080", "#87CEFA", "#00FF00", "#FFA500", "#FF0000")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")

> chart
  plotvals  Colour
1      0.2 #000080
2      0.4 #87CEFA
3      0.6 #00FF00
4      0.8 #FFA500
5      1.0 #FF0000
```

I can create the plot on the left as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(pos = c(82304304L, 82402792L, 82567842L, 82646930L, 
82686681L), val = c(0.0336705048361217, 0.0304909014034332, 3.21204387671607, 
2.28366271211045, 1.7182850299727), Colour = c("#000080", "#000080", 
"#87CEFA", "#00FF00", "#87CEFA")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L), class = "data.frame")

> df
       pos       val  Colour
1 82304304 0.0336705 #000080
2 82402792 0.0304909 #000080
3 82567842 3.2120439 #87CEFA
4 82646930 2.2836627 #00FF00
5 82686681 1.7182850 #87CEFA


plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(pos, rep(1, times = nrow(df)))) + 
      geom_point(shape = "\u007C", size = 5) + 
      theme_void() 

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(pos, val, colour = Colour)) +
      geom_point() + 
      ylim(0, 4) +
      theme_bw() +
      scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")

plots <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2, heights = c(0.5, 6),
    ncol = 1, nrow = 2, align = "v", common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right")

png("plots.png")
plots
dev.off()
```

How do I adjust the legend so that it is custom, but still functions with ggarrange?

Comment: Are you tied to `ggarrange`? There could be better options using the cowplot or patchwork packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this works for your real case but for the example data one option would be to set the `limits` and the `labels` of the color scale according to your `chart` df plus some additional hacks via `guide_legend`, i.e. use a rectangle `shape` and setting the `size`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(pos, rep(1, times = nrow(df)))) +
  geom_point(shape = "\u007C", size = 5) +
  theme_void()

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(pos, val)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Colour)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_identity(
    guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5)),
    limits = chart$Colour, labels = scales::number(chart$plotvals)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = chart$Colour)

plots <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2,
  heights = c(0.5, 6),
  ncol = 1, nrow = 2, align = "v", common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right"
)
```

[image]